# Executing gmail_auth() in r using command line asks for authentication every time

Tags: r, command-line, rscript, gmailr

I'm executing an R script from the command line:

```
library(gmailr)
gmail_auth(scope = c("read_only", "modify", "compose", "full"), 
    secret_file = "C:\\Sentiment Analysis from Email in R\\client.json")
```

But it's asking for authentication each and every time. How to prevent this? But in RStudio, it only asks once. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you set `options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)`? When you are using Rstudio presumably you are keeping the same R session alive. When you run Rscript multiple times, you are creating new R sessions each time.

Comment: Ya, including httr_oauth file in the same working directory solved the problem. Thank you!